# Is there any way to represent any number as sum of 4 squares?

Tags: java

Is there any way to represent any number as sum of 4 squares.

For example 29 can be represented as 5^2+2^2+0^2+0^2

I tried the following code but some numbers giving 5terms for example 23 as 4^2+2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2

the code i tried is :

```
 x=0;
 while(num!=0){
          x=(int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
         num=num-(x*x);        
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is trivial, there is an algorithm linked from the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Algorithms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike what Bohemian said, I solved 23 in 4 terms as follows:

```
23 = 3^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2
```

And 29 as follows:

```
29 = 4^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 0^2
```

My logic would start as:

1. Start with the square root of the number - 1. E.g. `SQRT(29) = 5 - 1 = 4;` This is now our first term.
2. Take value from point 1), square it and add to it again the squared value from point 1) and see if it's greater than N. If it is, decrement the 2nd sum term by 1 and add it the squared value to value from 1).
3. If the previous squared value terms sums are less than N, find next value term and repeat 2) until you have all 4 terms that adds up to N.

**Note**: This is for your simple case. For complex case like e.g. 323, this might not work.

```
323 = 17^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 3^2
```

Bear in mind, as you find the x term, the term's value is **less than or equal to** the x-1 (previous) term's value.

Comment: So much for taking coffee break while posting. I post my answer over 30 minutes.

Comment: E.g. using 29, from point 1) you get the value 4, this is our first term. Now, we use first term value as 2nd sum term and add it to the squared value of first sum term from 1), e.g. 4^2 + 4^2 = 32. Since 32 > 29, we decrement the 2nd value term by 1, so 4 becomes 3. Now we test again, 4^2 + 3^2 = 25. 25 < 29, so let's find the 3rd sum term. Loop point 2 again until you find all 4 terms.

Comment: You will loop up to 4. That's all you can do.

Comment: given a number n ,how can we guarantee that  uisng the above logic we can find 4 numbers such that their sum of squares will be equal to that number

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2601/discussion-between-user605343-and-the-elite-gentleman)

Comment: @user605343, See [Lagrange's Four Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Algorithms). There must be an algorithm on the web.

Comment: this is not working for numbers from 1 to 8,even for 11 and so on

Comment: @user605343, I did mention at each term is **less than or equal** to the previous term** (left of it), so `1 = 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2`, so the solution is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the algorithm code for you

This will give you all possible combinations ...

```
int n, t1, t2, t;
        n = 29;//Your number

        for (int i = (int) Math.sqrt(n / 4); i * i <= n; i++) {
            t1 = n - i * i;
            for (int j = (int) Math.sqrt(t1 / 3); j <= i && j * j <= t1; j++) {
                t2 = t1 - j * j;
                for (int k = (int) Math.sqrt(t2 / 2); k <= j && k * k <= t2; k++) {
                    t = (int) Math.sqrt(t2 - k * k);
                    if (t <= k && t * t == t2 - k * k) {
                        System.out.println("(" + i + "^2) + (" + j + "^2) + ("+ k + "^2) + ("+ t +"^2)");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Brute force is far from optimal, or even usable.

Comment: @bdares Can u suggest some better options??

Comment: The [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Algorithms) has been shown to solve the problem in O(logn). This is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 4):

After initially answering incorrectly, I thought I'd code it up: This solution works.

I have tested this code and it performs in O(log n) time, up to very large numbers (solves for n=Long.MAX_VALUE in 75 ms on an old macbook pro)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number = 827347833323423451L;
    LinkedList<Long> solution = new LinkedList<Long>();
    if (fourSquares(number, solution))
        System.out.println(number + " = sum of squares of: " + solution);
    else
        System.out.println(number + " could not be solved"); // never happens
}

public static boolean fourSquares(long number, LinkedList<Long> solution) {
    if (number == 0) {
        for (long i = solution.size(); i < 4; i++)
            solution.add(0L);
        return true;
    }

    if (solution.size() == 4)
        return false;

    for (long i = (long) Math.sqrt(number); i > 0; i--) {
        solution.add(i);
        if (fourSquares(number - i * i, solution))
            return true;
        solution.removeLast();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
9223372036854775807 = sum of squares of: [3037000499, 76994, 671, 23]
```

Comment: Try 9223372036854775800 (I'm curious).

Comment: @nneonneo passing `9223372036854775800` through this code takes 50ms to correctly complete. [See it running on IDEOne](https://ideone.com/EfaDtW).

Comment: Irritatingly enough, after four years I'm not entirely sure why I asked you that question. However, I do note that your algorithm doesn't seem to be O(log n) - if hypothetically a number had no combinations, your algorithm would test every combination, for what appears to be O(sqrt(n)^4) or O(n^2) work.

Comment: @nneo yes, I suspect it was a challenge to test performance. TBH I was a little scared it would timeout. I agree with your assessment of the algorithm in the worst case, but (obviously) it converges quickly enough once it gets a hit.

Comment: Try this one 100010000000L maybe. It takes 60 seconds on my machine. The problem is that it tries to find the largest four squares which need not be close to sqrt(N) like @nneonneo pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

So, I couldn't put this out of my mind and solved it in Java using dynamic programming, specifically, memoization.

Here's the relevant bits:

```
private final Map<Integer, int[]> memo = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();

/**
 * @param n
 *        the number
 * @return int[]
 */
public int[] solveFor(final int n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    final int[] a = new int[4];
    a[0] = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
    if (sumOfSquares(a) < n) {
        int[] b = solveFor(n - a[0] * a[0]);
        while (a[0] > 0 && b[3] > 0) {
            // won't fit
            a[0]--;
            b = solveFor(n - a[0] * a[0]);
        }
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 1, 3);
    }
    memo.put(n, a);
    return a;
}
```

On this lowly 2.4GHz i5 it can calculate all decompositions from 0 to 2,000,000 in less than 3 seconds.

The obvious downside, of course, is it can quickly run out of memory if asked to compute for all integers up to a large-ish number. But if it's just asked to solve for, say, 42 million, it can churn out the correct answer in a couple of milliseconds.

I'm also pretty sure it can still be improved/optimized—specifically the part that just decrements the first term if it finds the solution for remainder is too long to fit in the remaining spaces, but I'll leave that as an exercise for people who have better math skills and more free time. :)

Answer (score 1):

this hard to implement since if a prime number comes in between you can never break it to be square root of 1; for example,

take 11,

3^2--- now 2 remains and it does't have square root and the number less than this is "1", and 1^(n) is always 1.. so always there remains a reminder..

so may be you need to follow some kind of algorithms as other answers suggest...

Comment: Exactly. If you walk through the algorithm the OP presented, it'll decompose 11 into 3, 1, 1.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

23 simply requires 5 terms to solve.

Try counting the number of terms and terminating the loop if the limit of 4 is reached.

#### EDITED:

See my other (better) answer

Comment: i know 23 requires 5 terms by the way iam following...but i want some suggestion from to you to represent any number as sum of squares of four terms

Comment: @Bohemain, [Lagrange's Four Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Algorithms) has been proven and 23 can be solved with 4 terms (See my answer). – The Elite Gentleman 6 hours ago